# Simulate ExchangeServer web service

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices, exchange-server

As you already know, Win7 Outlook can connect to ExchangeServer. 
http://www.washington.edu/itconnect/wares/uwexchange/outlook2010.html

I want to develop server app in C#, to which Outlook will be able to connect too.
All in order to sync my server data (contacts, calendar, tasks, etc.) with Outlook.

What I know is that ExchangeServer use EWS for client communication.
Can I develop web service based on EWS Managed API to communicate/sync with Outlook ?

If cannot, what are the other options(managed or unmanaged code) ?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why this couldn't be done - after all, GMail emulates the Exchange ActiveSync protocol.

You might find it is infeasibly difficult though.

A reasonable starting point might be to capture and analyse some of the network traffic between Outlook and Exchange to see what you're up against.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use the EWS managed API which i believe is written in C# and use request all the data you need. You could then wrap the response you get from the EWS calls in your own RESTful/SOAP webservice which you can expose to whoever needs to use it.

If you only want to get data for your own personal use then you probably don't need to wrap the EWS managed API calls in your own webservice. Just use the results you get from Exchange for whatever you need.

Another alternative would be to use the WEB Service which comes with Exchange out of the box. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb421489(v=exchg.80).aspx) Its a SOAP web service and provides all the same functionality as you'll find with the managed API and it will give you your web service. I have worked with the EWS SOAP web service and find it very powerful and plenty of online support

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simulate/emulate EWS APIs to achieve what you intend to. But there are couple of things you may want to have a look -
1. Outlook uses MAPI API to connect with exchange so I am not sure if outlook has EWS client in built? My best guess is that it doesn't have it.

In this case this is what you need to do - 
1. crate an outlook plugin which uses ews client apis to sync contacts/calendar etc.
2. create ews service which will talk to this client and do sync stuff.

Alternatively you can also use activesync api's at both end but EWS is your better bet since you will get lot of community support for it.

While it may seem bit difficult but in reality it is not.